# Multiple HTTP GET methods in ASP.NET Core WebAPI

Tags: asp.net-core, routes, asp.net-core-webapi, http-get

I started to experiment on ASP.NET Core Web API and while writing a controller to assist multiple get requests which are differed by number of parameters, I am getting the below error.

> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Matching.AmbiguousMatchException: The
> request matched multiple endpoints. Matches:
>
> PaperRocket.Controllers.Products.ProductsController.GetProducts
> (PaperRocket)
> PaperRocket.Controllers.Products.ProductsController.GetProduct
> (PaperRocket)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Matching.DefaultEndpointSelector.ReportAmbiguity(CandidateState[]
> candidateState)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Matching.DefaultEndpointSelector.ProcessFinalCandidates(HttpContext
> httpContext, CandidateState[] candidateState)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Matching.DefaultEndpointSelector.Select(HttpContext
> httpContext, CandidateState[] candidateState)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Matching.DfaMatcher.MatchAsync(HttpContext
> httpContext)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Matching.DataSourceDependentMatcher.MatchAsync(HttpContext
> httpContext)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointRoutingMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
> httpContext)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
> context)
>
> HEADERS
> ======= Accept: */* Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br Cache-Control: no-cache Connection: keep-alive Host: localhost:54967 User-Agent:
> PostmanRuntime/7.24.1 Postman-Token:
> 0f3ce4b4-283a-472b-9350-7b0cc02d31ae

So, my question is, can we have multiple get Methods

1. which are differed by number of parameters(Which is possible in WEB-API)
2. Without using HTTPGET("RouteConstraint")-(I know with this, it will work)
3. respective method should get called and identified by the the parameters that we passed

Below is my code:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<Product> GetProducts()
    {
        return _Productcontext.GetProducts();
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public Product GetProduct([FromQuery(Name = "ProductCode")]string ProductCode)
    {
        return _Productcontext.GetProductByProductCode(ProductCode);
    }
```

Comment: If I am not mistaken in Web API controller method the default binding is [FromQuery], so you can't have many get methods, with different parameters, without changing the route or adding [FromRoute] parameters.

Comment: I have been struggling with this. Any articles suggestions to go through.

Comment: Maybe this can help: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/?view=aspnetcore-3.1#binding-source-parameter-inference , https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/webapi/parameter-binding-in-web-api

Comment: The short answer is NO. Method overloading is not possible with Web API. Either differentiate them with routes or with different method names. From the example code that you have posted, i think a method with product code is sufficient in both cases. When product code is supplied use that to fetch that specific product, when it is not specified (null or empty) just get everything.

Comment: Hi @NaredlaNitheshReddy, any updates about this case?

Comment: @FeiHan...I opted to use route attribute..though not satisfied with it

Answer (score 0):

> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Matching.AmbiguousMatchException: The request matched multiple endpoints.

You can try to enable or disable an action for a given request based on query string that you passed by implementing a custom [ActionMethodSelectorAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.actionconstraints.actionmethodselectorattribute?view=aspnetcore-3.1), like below.

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = true)]
public class CheckProductCodeAttribute : ActionMethodSelectorAttribute
{
    public string QueryStingName { get; set; }
    public bool CanPass { get; set; }
    public CheckProductCodeAttribute(string qname, bool canpass)
    {
        QueryStingName = qname;
        CanPass = canpass;
    }

    public override bool IsValidForRequest(RouteContext routeContext, ActionDescriptor action)
    {
        StringValues value;

        routeContext.HttpContext.Request.Query.TryGetValue(QueryStingName, out value);

        if (QueryStingName == "" && CanPass)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            if (CanPass)
            {
                return !StringValues.IsNullOrEmpty(value);
            }

            return StringValues.IsNullOrEmpty(value);
        }
    }
}
```

Apply to your actions

```
[HttpGet]
[CheckProductCode("", true)]
[CheckProductCode("ProductCode", false)]
public IEnumerable<Product> GetProducts()
{
    return _Productcontext.GetProducts();
}

[HttpGet]
[CheckProductCode("", false)]
[CheckProductCode("ProductCode", true)]
public Product GetProduct([FromQuery(Name = "ProductCode")]string ProductCode)
{
    return _Productcontext.GetProductByProductCode(ProductCode);
}
```